# Raspberry Pi 3 Raspbian open port or make my webapp accessible from LAN

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, node.js

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian OS. I installed nodejs on it and started node server on port 3000. I can open it from Raspberry Pi but I can't open it from local network. All I need is to run a web app on my RPI and make it accessible from local network.

This is how I can open it on Raspberry:
[image]

This is what I see if I try to open it from other computer in the network:
[image]

Same thing if I try to access it by ip. So how can I make my web app available for other computers in the network?

Comment: If your Pi is connected via a router you need to configure the router.  Configuring a router is not relevant to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @joan it has nothing to do with the router. I can connect to Pi via the rdp or putty, which means it's in the network, I want to access it via HTTP as well and I have a server running on it, I just need to open a port.

Comment: *"It's like behind the firewall or something..."* -> You need to make more of an effort to describe the problem if you want an informed opinion about it.

Comment: That is not a description of the problem.  That is an elaboration of *your diagnosis* (firewall) which, if correct, means it has nothing to do with the pi because **there is no firewall active by default on Raspbian**.  Perhaps it is a firewall involving the machines you are trying to access the pi from.

Comment: @goldilocks please see the screenshots attached. Maybe this will make it more clear for you.

Comment: Yeah.  **It makes it more clear it has nothing to do with a firewall on the Pi.**  But since you've described the problem I will reopen it.

Comment: I apologize for being a bit snippy.   I don't think chrome will say "refused to connect" in response to ICMP packets from a firewall; it will say "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE".  In both cases the big message will be "This site can't be reached", but if the reason for that is "connection refused" it implies there's nothing listening on the port, so perhaps you have the wrong IP associated with the hostname.   Anyway, you can check any firewall rules currently being applied on the pi with `sudo iptables -L`.  It will probably show three empty chains with ALLOW as the default policy.

Comment: I think your server app just listens to 127.0.0.1, set it to 0.0.0.0

Comment: @vaha it works! Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: @Andrei M, the answer is posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to connect to `127.0.0.1` (in other words the loopback IP) does not mean that the server app is bound to all network interfaces of the system.

To listen all existing or will be existed interfaces, an app should be bound to the address `0.0.0.0`.

By this way, remote clients will be able to connect to the corresponding IP adresses.